# Question about degree of field extension in Galois Theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I have the following exercise:

Let $\mathbb{C}\left(e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}\right) \subset \mathbb{C}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right)$ be the subfield of symmetric functions where

$e_{1}=x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}, \quad e_{2}=x_{1} x_{2}+x_{1} x_{3}+x_{2} x_{3}, \quad e_{3}=x_{1} x_{2} x_{3}$

Find the degree of the extension of $\mathbb{C}\left(e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}\right)$ generated by the element 
$x_{1}+2 x_{2}+3 x_{3} \in \mathbb{C}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right)$.

I think that I should use the fact that the Galois group of $\mathbb{C}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right)/\mathbb{C}\left(e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}\right)$ is $S_{3}$ and probably the tower law for the intermediate extension, but that does not lead me anywhere. I have not seen something similar before, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E = ℂ(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, $F = ℂ(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ and $G = \operatorname{Gal} (E/F) \cong S_3$.

The intermediate fields of $E/F$ are the fixed fields $E^H$ corresponding to subgroups $H$ of $G$, so $ℂ(α) = E^H$ for some subgroup $H ⊆ G$.

What are the permutations of $G$ that fix $α = x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3$? Writing $ℂ(α) = E^H$ for some subgroup $H ⊆ G$, what can you conclude about $ℂ(α)$?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. We can see that $\alpha$ is fixed only by the identity map, hence $\mathbb{C}(\alpha)$ must be the whole field $E$.